# Errors from dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a very strange problem that occurs once in a while and I don't know what it triggers. Here are my relevant package versions:

```
"react-router@^4.3.1"
"react-router-dom@^4.3.1"
```

It probably has to do something with the versions I guess, because this problem doesn't occur sometimes. But when I delete `node_modules` and build the project with `npm install`, I get the following error:

```
browser.js:34 Uncaught Error: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
    at invariant (browser.js:34)
    at Link.render (Link.js:113)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15320)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15275)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:16265)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:20285)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:20326)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19509)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:20439)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21363)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:21273)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:21247)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:21102)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:20915)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:11596)
    at LoadableComponent.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:336)
    at update (index.js:240)
    at index.js:250
```

There is no way that I use the `Link` outside `Router`.

So now I face this issue again and even though I check out different version/branches of my project, and then delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then to `npm install`: The problem cannot be solved. The error message remains the same as above.

So my question is: What else can be the cause of a problem that wasn't there on other branches but appear when deleting `node_modules` and suddenly appear on all other branches?

**EDIT:**

```
<HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/activateprofile" name="Benutzerkonto aktivieren" component={Activation} />
          <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" component={Page404} />
          <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" component={Page500} />
          <PrivateRoute path='/' component={DefaultLayout} />
        </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: This most likely is not a problem with the node modules, rather its with your code at `browser.js`, line 34, according to the stack.

Comment: Wrap your App inside Router and you will your error vanish like <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>

Comment: @tarzenchugh I tried it but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @KobanDavis But this file is not from me but from the dependency

Comment: Please provide reproducible code many be codesandbox link to help you on this.